# What does Ron mean by "watch who you eat"?

Tags: plot-explanation, dallas-buyers-club

There is a scene where Ron Woodroof says to a gay couple: "Watch what you eat and who you eat". What does he mean when he says "watch who you eat" ? What's the problem with the person you eat with?

Comment: The title made me think this was going to be a Harry Potter question.  Whoops!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

'Eating' is slang for fellatio (see definition 7 [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/eat)). By saying "watch out *who* you eat", he's humorously telling them to be careful whom they have sex with.